# Is it possible to classify kubernetes pod logs collected by fluentd?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, fluentd

Currently, fluentd is used to collect logs produced by kubernetes pods, which are located under `/var/log/containers/'. The problem is that different kinds of pods may have different log formats. And I want to classify those log files so that they can be processed distinctively.

Can I add labels to kubernetes pods, such as `log4j`, `python_log`, and detected by fluentd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fluent plugin kubernetes metadata filter](https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter) to get the pod's metadata and classify it with other approach.

Comment: I don't know how this answer is accepted. This can't match the pod by a label to apply a different parsing config.